# Difficulty with workings of SQL IN

Tags: mysql

My understanding is that IN is like a boolean function returning a value for each instance a row from the outside query has true returned when using IN. Therefore shouldn't a result set  only have as many rows as the outer query?

Table 1:

```
   DNUMBER DLOCATION
---------- ---------------
         1 Houston
         4 Stafford
         5 Bellaire
         5 Houston
         5 Sugarland
```

Table 2:

```
DNAME                   DNUMBER
-------------------- ----------
Research                      5
Administration                4
Headquarters                  1
```

So shouldn't this query only return 3 rows?

```
SELECT D.dname, DL.dlocation
FROM department D, dept_locations DL
WHERE D.dnumber IN
(SELECT dnumber FROM dept_locations)
```

Result:

```
DNAME                DLOCATION
-------------------- -------------
Headquarters         Houston
Administration       Houston
Research             Houston
Headquarters         Stafford
Administration       Stafford
Research             Stafford
Headquarters         Bellaire
Administration       Bellaire
Research             Bellaire
Headquarters         Houston
Administration       Houston
Research             Houston
Headquarters         Sugarland
Administration       Sugarland
Research             Sugarland
```

Comment: In works like an array of sorts, so you're basically saying "Where D.number is present in this array (5, 4, 1)"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT D.dname, DL.dlocation
FROM department D, dept_locations DL
WHERE D.dnumber IN
(SELECT dnumber FROM dept_locations)
```

Has no join criteria (explicit or implicit) restricting the rows to be matched in any way, so performs a cross join (all combinations of rows on the left with rows on the right).

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of IN is correct. The reason you're getting more rows is because your main query is selecting from 2 tables and there is no limitation on the second one. This query will only return 3 rows:

```
SELECT D.dname
FROM department D
WHERE D.dnumber IN
(SELECT dnumber FROM dept_locations)
```

But of course you'd lose your location. By adding `dept_locations` to the `FROM` clause, you're basically cross-joining the tables, and you're not limiting the rows returned from the second table with your `WHERE` clause, you're only limiting the rows from `department`

To properly limit the rows returned using your current query format, you could do this:

```
SELECT D.dname, DL.dlocation
FROM department D, dept_locations DL
WHERE D.dnumber IN
(SELECT dnumber FROM dept_locations)
AND DL.dnumber = D.dnumber
```

But the best way to get the data you want is probably to use a `JOIN` here:

```
SELECT D.dname, DL.dlocation
FROM department D
JOIN dept_locations DL on DL.dnumber = D.dnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT D.dname
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DL.dlocation)
  FROM department AS D 
 INNER 
  JOIN dept_locations AS DL 
    ON D.dnumber = DL.dnumber 
 GROUP 
    BY D.dname;
```

I'm making a few assumptions, but I think this will return the data you're trying to get. It'll grab each type (research, etc) alongside a comma separated list of locations.

Your query doesn't need a subquery at all, just a proper join conditional.